# unable to execute javascript jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a Jquery autocomplete function through callback method. However it doesn't seem to run.

Here is my code:

At Client-Side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
                alert("hi");
                 $("#Text1").autocomplete({
                     minLength: 0,
                     source: function (request, response) {
                         $.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                             url: 'BlissMaker.aspx/GetNames',
                             data: "{ 'sname':'" + request.term + "' }",
                             dataType: "json",
                             dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                             success: function (data) {
                                 if (data.d != null) {
                                     response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                         return {
                                             label: item.Name,
                                             value: item.Id
                                         }
                                     }))
                                 }
                             },
                             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                 alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                             }
                         });
                     },
                     focus: function (event, ui) {
                         $("#Text1").val(ui.item.label);
                         return false;
                     }
                 })
                    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                        return $("<li></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append("<a><img src='" + item.icon + "' width='32' height='32' />  " + item.Name + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    };
            }
</script>
```

At Code-Behind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<States> GetNames(string sname)
{
    List<States> sbStates = new List<States>();
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRATEEK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BD;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    con.Open();

Me mee = (Me)Session["Me"];

qr = "SELECT FBFriends.FB_Id2, ActiveInfo.Name, ActiveInfo.Profile_Pic, ActiveInfo.Gender FROM [FBFriends],[ActiveInfo] WHERE FBFriends.FB_Id1='" + mee.Id + "' AND ActiveInfo.FB_Id=FBFriends.FB_Id2";
ds = new DataSet(qr);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(qr, con);
da.Fill(ds);

ds.Tables[0].Select(ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName + " Like '%" + sname + "%' and " + ds.Tables[0].Columns[3].ColumnName + " = 'Female'");

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    States st = new States();
    st.Id = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    st.Name = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    st.Value = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    st.Icon = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
    sbStates.Add(st);
}

    return sbStates;
}
```

It seems that autocomplete function is not getting called as well as Alert()..
Any suggestions on how to call it?

**ADDED:**
After checking the stack trace, it gives me an error

> Unknown Method name GetNames

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you output returned data object in the console ? Just to make sure the callback success is called.

Comment: why you do not open the javascript error to see the error by your self before bring them up here ?

Comment: @vini Combine all 3 of our answers, _jk._ says there are multiple syntax errors (one of which is the missing parenthesis _Marcin Necsord Szulc_ brought up) you need to fix. Then replace the string literals in the `data:` section with a variable called `dataToSend` (or whatever you want it to be called). Then run it, it _should_ work after all that.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work. i believe my callback is not getting called. i traced but gives unknown method GetNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank You everyone**. I finally got my mistake.
The Web Method needed to be **Static** in order to call it and also ScriptManager included in the form must be `EnablePageMethods=true`

My code is working all fine now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot one closing at the end ")";

```
$(document).ready(function() {
})
```

After fixing that part check the response and request in console of firebug or such.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning up the code errors and run it again:

```
Problem at line 19 character 43: Missing semicolon.
}

Problem at line 20 character 41: Missing semicolon.
}))

Problem at line 39 character 13: Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
}

Problem at line 39 character 13: Missing semicolon.
}
```

Comment: thats just a problem in pasting code. its all fine otherwise. i am asking for logical errors

Comment: @vini You said: `It seems that autocomplete function is not getting called as well as Alert(). Any suggestions on how to call it?` The coding errors were why your `alert` wasn't firing and the `autocomplete` was not getting called. You asked why it wasn't. You can't address logic errors if the code doesn't run.

Comment: i believe you took the question in a wrong meaning. The function is not getting called means it wasn't showing any results nor reacting to my breakpoint which i applied on code-behind. However i admit i didn't check the Intellisense which says unknown method. Now can you help me with that?

Comment: @vini I took it exactly as written. You said `it doesn't seem to run` and then asked how to call the `autocomplete` function. I answered that and then got downvoted. Don't know how that happened. Now you are clarifying something after the fact.

Comment: I have figured out a solution sorry for being rude

Answer (score 1):

Is `$(document).ready()` getting called at all? If not, is you javascript in a separate file? If so, maybe the file itself is not reachable and the `ready()` function isn't even being called. Check the `<script src=""></script>` tags for including the JQuery files and your javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is causing your problem or not, but I noticed in your JQuery `$.ajax` call you had this line here:

`data: "{ 'sname':'" + request.term + "' }",`

I've found ajax calls to fail if I concat variables and strings in the `data:` field of the `$.ajax` call.

**Try this:**

declare a variable outside the call like this:

`var dataToSend = "{ 'sname':'" + request.term + "' }";`

then change the `data:` field to this:

`data: dataToSend,`

This may or may not solve your problem, but it looks nicer! Try it anyways!